# How can be achieved the parallelism in java code with single CPU?

Tags: java

How come in JMS(Java Messaging Services) technology we achieved two thread execute simultaneously on single CPU based system?

Comment: You oughta sell  the techonology to the CPU vendors, that would be amazing. On a more serious note: if you consider "same time" the one returned by `System.currentTimeMillis()` it's absolutely possible. the clock is not very precise, smth like 16ms on windows

Answer (score 4):

You can still have two threads executing, but on a single core they won't be *genuinely* executing at the same time. They can both be runnable, and take turns executing without any extra work on the developer's part - and quite often you may well find that one is blocked (e.g. on IO) while another can use the CPU.

If you believe you've seen two threads *genuinely* running on the same single core at the same time (without hyperthreading etc), I think you should describe exactly what has brought you to that conclusion - I suspect you're seeing the *illusion* of multiple threads, just by time-slicing (just as you can run multiple processes on a single core, and it *looks* like they're "all running at the same time").

Comment: Then How JMS works on this as parallel processing multiple requests?

Comment: @satyajitKumar: The same way you can run a web browser and Word on a single core machine at a time - pre-emptive multitasking. Just time-slicing, basically.

Answer (score 1):

The multi-threading in Java is conceptually very close to the way that an operating system - e.g. Microsoft Windows - let several programs run at the same time.

The thing is that "at the same time" is only apparent because CPU's are so fast, and we humans are slow.   What *actually* happens, is that each program gets to run for a few milliseconds all by it self, and then the operating system let the next program run for the next few milliseconds, and then the next etc, until we reach back to the first program.   It takes a little bit of time to switch to the next program so the length of the interval is chosen to minimize this overhead while still giving reasonable performance.

The same thing goes for Java threads - each thread gets its share of the processor, and something "outside" your program ensures this - but to *you* it seems like they run at the same time.

Comment: Then why we used multithreading concepts rather sequential single threaded model ?

Comment: @satyajitKumar: Because we want two things: 1) to utilize the CPU idle time during I/O and other non-CPU intensive work. (2) and because we want to server more customers(processes)

Comment: because single CPU, single core, systems are rare these days, especially on the type of systems that typically run server software.
And on multi-CPU systems you can run multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: @satyajit, because it is more convenient to be able to.  I don't know if you are old enough to have experienced this first hand, but MS-DOS computers (before Windows) _could_ only run one program at a time.  I.e. _either_ you read mail, _or_ you code, _or_ you surf.

Comment: @jwenting, most - if not all - low end systems still have single cores.

Comment: @Thorbjørn, back in the days the only "simultaneous" operation was an interrupt (timer, kbd, disk, etc) and the code just interrupting the execution. Reprogramming 8259 (the interrupt controller), so the default interrupt vector points somewhere else was a true hacking and adventure...

Comment: @bestsss, I remember Borland Sidekick well.

Comment: @Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen : I think in window system also, if you consider java programming the same things like in old MS-DOS system? Is not it?

Comment: @satyajit, no, because even if both use a text based console window (like on Linux) the underlying operating system is vastly different.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to "time slicing". While one thread is waiting for something (E.g. response from DB), other threads can run.

The thread that is waiting for something is "blocked" till that thing happens.

If all threads are ready to run, CPU is shared and one thread is run for few milliseconds, and CPU is given to other thread after that.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is not restricted to single core machines. Even if you have 4 cores, you are likely to have hundreds or thousands of threads across all the processes in your system.  Basically they all have to take turns and this is the job of the operating system.  Java passes this work to the OS by using native threads (its not a requirement for Java but almost all versions do this)

So really the question is how does the OS support threads.  Thats depends on how your OS works but almost all use time-slices and voluntary release of the CPU.  A voluntary release can occur when you have a Thread.yield()/sleep() or blocking read/write or any operation which is performed in the OS and it can determine the thread must wait for something.  The OS can decide its not worth waiting because another thread is runnable and would like to do something.  The OS can preform a context switch allowing another thread/process to run.  This is a common behaviour in IO bound processes.

In CPU bound processes, the thread does not make a blocking call, and just uses the CPU.  When this happens, the thread is given a maximum time-slice and it is forced to give up the CPU instead.

Comment: @ALL: My query was : Is java's multithreading means multiple thread can execute simultaneously or just share the CPU in a single CPU system ? otherway can  a single CPU system can make two thread execution in a particular insatance of time ?

Comment: Either a CPU can execute multiple threads at once e.g. hyperthreading or multiple cores, or it can't if its a single CPU.  You have stated you have a single CPU which can only execute one thread at a time so you have answered your own question. Java just uses native threads so this is not a question specific to Java. From your point of view it will look like they are running at the same time.